# How would you solve this surface integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, integral-transforms

Suppose you had the surface integral $\iint \limits_{A} = x^{3}(1-x^{4}-y^{4})dx \ dy$ where $A$ is the region defined by $x \geq 0, \; y \geq 0, \; x^{4}+y^{4} \leq 1$.

How would you solve this using the substitution $x=\sqrt{R \ cos \theta}, \; y=\sqrt{R \ sin \theta}$?

Obviously this substitution gives us $x^{3}(1-x^{4}-y^{4})=(R \ cos \theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-R^{2})$, but what would this transformation make $dx \ dy$ become?

Also, is there any difference between a double integral and a surface integral, or are they the same thing?

Comment: Why do you want to use $x$ and $y$ defined like this, with the square roots and all?

Comment: I assume that these substitutions are used because it converts the integral to polar coordinates.

Comment: But these aren't polar coordinates. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: Have you tried computing the Jacobian determinant?

Comment: Do you mean the Jacobian determinant of $x^{3}(1-x^{4}-y^{4})$? If so, how is this relevant?

Comment: For your final question, *surface integrals* are to *double integrals* as [*line integrals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) are to regular single integrals. Are you simply computing the volume under the graph of $x^3(1-x^4-y^4)$ within the bounds of $A$? If so, it's just a double integral.

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer (too long for comment), but to expand on my previous comment:
$$\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=|J|\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\[1ex]\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{vmatrix}\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\sin2t}}\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$